# Не работает отправка формы методом POST!

Tags: php, html, post, email

Html код

```html
 <div class="podbor">
    <div class="row sectionTitle">
          <h2 class="this-title">Сложно сделать выбор?<br> Мы поможем Вам!</h2>
          
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top: 60px;">
      <div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Для квартиры или дома</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <form method="POST" action="zayavka2.php">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <fieldset>
    <legend>1. Тип помещения</legend>
      <select name="type[]">
        <option value="Квартира">Квартира</option>
        <option value="Дом">Дом</option>
        <option value="Офис">Офис</option>
      </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>2. Площадь помещения</legend>
      <select name="ploshad[]">
        <option value="До 20м2">До 20м2</option>
        <option value="От 20 до 30м2"> От 20 до 30м2</option>
        <option value="От 30 до 40м2">От 30 до 40м2</option>
        <option value="Более 40м2">Более 40м2</option>
      </select>
  </fieldset>
       <fieldset>
        <legend>3. Цена</legend>
      <select name="Cena[]">
        <option value="До 15тр">До 15тр</option>
        <option value="До 20тр">До 20тр</option>
        <option value="До 30тр">До 30тр</option>
        <option value="До 40тр">До 40тр</option>
      </select>
  </fieldset>
        
       <br><br><br>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="phone">
      </div>
      <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
   </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
       
    </div>
  
</div></div>
```

А вот PHP код

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</title>
</head>
 
<body>
 
<?php
   $back = "<p><a href=\"javascript: history.back()\">Вернуться назад</a></p>";
   
   if(!empty($_POST['type']) and !empty($_POST['ploshad']) and !empty($_POST['cena']) and !empty($_POST['phone']))
   {
      $type = trim(strip_tags($_POST['type']));
        $ploshad = trim(strip_tags($_POST['ploshad']));
       $cena = trim(strip_tags($_POST['cena']));
        $phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
      
          mail('pervushinmetal@gmail.com', 'Письмо с вашего сайта!', 
      'Заявка на подбор кондиционера с сайта!
      Его номер: '.$phone.'
      Тип: '$type'
      Площадь: '$ploshad'
      Цена: '$cena'
      ');
 
      echo "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!<Br> Вы получите ответ в 
      ближайшее время<Br> $back";
        
         exit;
      }
else {
      echo "Для отправки сообщения заполните все поля! $back";
      exit;
   }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: давно не видел такого ужаса
ну так а куда вы данные отправляете ? 
action="zayavka2.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте адрес страницы с которой отправляете форму. У вас в action указан относительный адрес, возможно проблема заключается в этом. А вообще посмотрите какой ответ приходит от сервера и многое встанет на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail('pervushinmetal@gmail.com', 'Письмо с вашего сайта!', 
  'Заявка на подбор кондиционера с сайта!
  Его номер: '.$phone.'
  Тип: '$type'
  Площадь: '$ploshad'
  Цена: '$cena'
  ');
```

$type, $ploshad, $cena - Эти переменные должны располагаться между точками.